# Make a singular button sleep/wake windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sleep, wakeup

I can't seem to find anything specific for windows 10.  I can search for the above title and it searches for everything with the word "Make" in it so it returns generic keyboard on/off settings adjustment.

My question is if there's a way to make a singular keyboard key sleep/wake the computer.  No mouse, not the whole keyboard, just 1 button.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

To put your computer into sleep mode, you can do windows + X, chord into U and then chord into S.

I don't think it would be possible to assign one specific key to wake your computer though, at least not with the default system settings. I guess the reason for that is that when your PC goes to sleep, it is set to react to any input rather than process the input and filter specific keys, most likely for power usage reason (usually why you put your computer to sleep).

It should be possible to write a program to change that behavior, but I don't think anyone has done it yet (or have published it).

Comment: Much appreciated Jeyzer!  I figured there wouldn't be a way to make a specific input wake the computer.  I have a 2 yr old that will sneak over and tappity tappity real fast then run away.  If I can turn off the ability to have the keyboard and mouse wake and have something else wake it that would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

- Keys can be remapped using
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.
  There are enough guides for this to go around, plus some tools (e.g. SharpKeys) to automate this entirely.
- You can prevent devices from being able to wake up the computer by disabling "allow this device to wake the computer" in Device Manager:
  [image]
- SharpKeys lists E0_63 as Fn/Wake button, but I have not tested how this interacts with above option.

With the above combined, computer would go to sleep at a press of a single (remapped) button and wake up only by pressing the Power button.